# Nuances when using fprintf

Tags: c++, printf

To preface - I'm a very novice c++ programmer. I'm working on a program to read through a file, do some logic, and output the results to a new file. fprintf is behaving curiously.

```
double address = 0;
while(!argfs.eof())                  //reading through my file
/*some code */                       //unrelated logic
fprintf(fpmif, "%d", address);       //write the address to my new file
/*some more code */                  //more unrelated logic
address++;                           //increment address and loop
```

The output file displays as I would expect, **except** that it always prints 0 for address. If I make address an __int64 and then change the fprintf statement to
    fprintf(fpmif, "%i", address);

Then the new file I'm writing to correctly displays the increasing address. Can anyone shed some light on what's happening here?

Thanks

Comment: `fprintf()` is [tag:c] BTW. Decide which language you want to use!

Comment: ... because in C++, we'd use `std::cout << address` and don't need to remember those `%d` codes.

Answer (score 4):

First, if you're just learning C++ don't write C code, which is what `fprintf` is. Learn how to do I/O with streams such as `ofstream` rather than C-style  I/O functions as they're more idiomatic and typesafe (as you learned the hard way).

Then carefully read up on format codes where you learn that `%d` is `int`. You want `%f`, `%e`, or `%g` for type `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behaviour. When you say `%d` in the format string, *you promise* that you will pass an `int` as the first variable argument. However, you are actually passing a `double`, thus lying to the compiler, and *anything could happen*.

To format a double, use the format specifier `%f`.